# How to find maximum value of trig function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, optimization

How to find maximum value of this:
$$y = 5\sin x - 12\cos x$$

And I am more intrested in solving process, rather than answer. I know the answer. I am familiar with derivatives, not so good, but as I found prime of this function:
$$y' = 5\cos x+12\sin x$$
but I dont know what to do next.

P.S Excuse me if grammar was poor, not a native english speaker.

Comment: Express as a single trig function of a different argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $y^{\prime}=0$ gives $5\cos x+12\sin x=0$, so $12\sin x=-5\cos x$ and dividing by $12\cos x$ gives

$\tan x=-\frac{5}{12}$.  Then $\sec^{2}x=1+\tan^{2}x=\frac{169}{144}$, so $\sec x=\pm\frac{13}{12}$ and $\cos x=\pm \frac{12}{13}$.

Then $\sin x=(\tan x)(\cos x)=\mp\frac{5}{13}$, so $y=\pm13$ at the critical points.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $a \cos x + b \sin y$ as $c \cos z$ for appropriate $c,z$ This
gives a periodic function which is straightforward to extremise.

We can write
$5 \sin x-12 \cos x = 13 ({5 \over 13} \sin x - {12 \over 13} \cos x)$, so
let $\phi$ be such that $\cos \phi = {5 \over 13}, \sin \phi = {12 \over 13}$
(such a $\phi$ exists since $5^2+12^2 = 13^2$). Then
$5 \sin x-12 \cos x = 13 \sin(x-\phi)$.

Since the range of $\sin$ is $ [-1,1]$, we see the maximum value is 13.

We see that the maximum value is attained 
for $x$ of the form $ \phi + (2n+1){\pi \over 2}$.

We have $\phi = \arctan {12 \over 5}$.

Comment: you meant $a \cos x + b \sin x$

Comment: @abel: Well, I was just pointing out the idea, since that was what the OP asked. I was presuming the OP was aware of the appropriate trigonometric formula. I will elaborate.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I did not understand, where you did get 13 straightforward.

Comment: $13 = \sqrt{12^2+5^2}$. I want to replace the $5,12$ in the formula by $\cos \phi, \sin \phi$, so I need a pair of numbers whose squares sum to one.

Comment: Great. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

i will finish what copper.hat is suggesting. we rewrite $$5\sin x - 12 \cos x = 13\left(\frac5{13}\sin x - \frac{12}{13}\cos x\right) = 13\sin (x-b), b = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{12}{13}\right) \tag 1$$

now you can read off the maximum of value of $5\sin x - 12 \cos x$ over any interval of length $2\pi$ is $13$ and it happens at $x = b +\pi/2.$

Comment: Thank you for help. I am not so good with trigonometry, trying it.

Comment: @Severus, you are welcome. enjoy, it gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This is equivalent to solving a system of two equations in two unknowns, $5a+12b=0$, and $a^2+b^2=1$.